# Creating custom event in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events

I have such usecase:

In my application some instances need to fire event, that they have been changes. But, I dont want to keep references to instances that need to be changed, so I would like to send event and somehow listen it in some places, but how to do it in C# in windows phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the EventAggregator. There are a few toolkits that you can build upon like [GalaSoft's MVVM Light](http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/) and [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/). You can find a good example of this at http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/.

The basic gist of it is to inject an EventAggregator into your ViewModel. This ViewModel would Publish an event. Other ViewModels would subscribe to this event.